# Dropdown plugin using jquery

Tags: jquery, plugins, drop-down-menu

I'm working on a dropdown plugin using lists. I got it working, except that if i have multiple dropdowns on the same page i'd like to close all the other ones except the one i'm triggering to close.

Here is what i have:

```
(function($){

  $.fn.dropDown = function(options) {
      var defaults = {
          wrapper: 'ul'
      }

    var settings = $.extend({}, defaults, options);


    $(this).find(settings.wrapper).hide();
    $(this).css("cursor","pointer");


        $(this).click(function(event) {
            elem= $(this);
            elem.find(settings.wrapper).toggle();
            elem.find("span").toggleClass("menuOpen");
            event.preventDefault();
            event.stopPropagation();
        });

        $(document).click(function() {  
                elem.find("span").removeClass("menuOpen");  
                elem.find(settings.wrapper).hide(); 
                elem.find(settings.wrapper).find("ul").show();  
        });
  };

})(jQuery);
```

and the plugin is called like this:

```
$('.dropdown').dropDown();
```

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance,
José

Answer (score 0):

I did something similar not too long ago.

A way to make all the *other* menus selectable by your code would be to give them a custom class when it runs, something like this:

`$(this).addClass("__my_menu");`

This way you have a handle on the menus that your plugin has setup.
So, when you want to close all menus apart from the current one, all you need to do is:

`$('.__my_menu').not($(this)).hide();`

Another point is that in your `document` click handler, the var `elem` is not set so it will never do anything. You should use `$(this)` instead.

Further reading:

use `$.off` and `$.on` instead of `$.click` (on jQuery 1.7 and above) : http://api.jquery.com/on/

`$.not` and other filtering methods: http://api.jquery.com/category/traversing/filtering/

Hope this helps and good luck.